# Is there a big advantage to using SDWebImage over AFNetworking for image loading?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, sdwebimage

[SDWebImage claims](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/wiki/How-is-SDWebImage-better-than-X%3F) that AFNetworking doesn't cache the image itself but just the HTTP response, so SDWebImage is faster in recalling the image from cache and presenting it.

If I wanted to use purely AFNetworking, is such a claim, true or not, really something that is noticeable performance-wise? Is it something I should be wary of?

Comment: There is a Q&A about SDWebImage VS AFNetworking in hacker news  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4237214

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SDWebImage has much more control over image caching. It can cache to disk or memory.

AFNetworking relies on NSURLCache to persist images between app launches (and it's not very reliable), but it's great if you just need to cache during one run.

Both solutions cache a UIImage object in memory during the lifetime of the app.  This is important because caching the NSData representation isn't fast enough to load images smoothly when scrolling through a table view.

Summary: AFNetworking's solution is simpler and will work for most use cases.  If you need finer control, or disk caching, use SDWebImage instead of modifying AFNetworking's implementation.

Comment: SDWebImage is very convenient especially with the progressive image download. But it’s based out of **NSURLConnection** ( even in the latest version 3.7.5 ) and we know that that is deprecated starting iOS 9. NSURLSession has been around for 3+ years now. Surprisingly SDWebImage has still not migrated to NSURLSession. 

See the SDWebImage: [Migration to NSURLSessions](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/1291).

**AFNetworking 3.0** is completely based on NSURLSession. So I think AfNetworking would a better choice than SDWebImage.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true.

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.m), you can see that the category `UIImageView+AFNetworking` cache the `UIImage` (using `NSCache` and the `urlRequest` as the key). The cache isn't written to disk though.

Answer (score 2):

I have used both :

SDWebImage is much much faster then UIImage + AFNetworking .

In UITableViewCell you can see the significant difference in performance . It was taking a hell lot of time in AFNetworking and the code is also too long . SDWebImage is much faster and short .

Use SDWebImage for better Image performance .

Comment: I am already using AFNetworking for restful communication with server. Would it be effective to use SDWebImage for images or AFNetworking would suffice?

Comment: Yeah SDWebImage performance is better then what i have seen of AFNetworking. If your application plays with lots of image better go with SDWebImage.